# Quick question to fresh up my mind, how to solve this logarithm without calculator?

Tags: logarithms

Please give an exact answer. And please explain it step by step please. It might be an easy question for you guys, but right now I don't get it.

Need it for my ICT study.

[formula as picture here, i dont know how to insert formula's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhyMX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $a \log(b) = \log(b^a)$ so you have $10^{\log(5^{-2})}$ which is just $5^{-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

OK. There's a few things to know: I'm sure you recall the power rule of exponents: [x^a]^b=x^ab.

You should know the def. of logs: z=log[sub b]a <=> b^z=a (here think: the base of the log has "come underneath" to become the base of the exponent).

Now we will show that the operation of logs is the opposite of exponentiation:

(1) To show: (log sub b)b^x=x

First let z=(log sub b)b^x. You let something = the log so you may use your def of logs. Now, applying the def,

b^z=b^x

=>z=x  & substituting back in for z,

(log sub b)b^x=x.

(2)To show: b^(log sub b)^x =x

Let z=log sub b)b^x

Then, by our def, b^z=b^x

=> z=x. Substituting back in for z,

b^(log sub b)^x=x.

Also recall that log stands for log(sub 10); that is, base 10.

Now the problem:

10^[-2log(sub 10) 5]

10^[log(sub 10) 5]^(-2) by power rule of exp.

5^(-2)

1/25.

Logs are not hard; but tricky!